# curl redirect to wrong page?

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl and I am passing a url, with page no=2 but it redirects to first page. I need your help. Please help me

Example:

If I passed http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/mobile-software-applications/id6018?mt=8&letter=A&page=2#page

it redirects to= http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/mobile-software-applications/id6018?mt=8&letter=A&page=1#page

```
<?php

$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/mobile-software-  applications/id6018?mt=8&letter=A&page=2#page");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else{
  echo $output = curl_exec($ch);  
}
curl_close($ch);  
?>
```

but it always redirects to first page, I am not getting page 2 or the given url.

Comment: You do realize you're calling exec twice, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the hashed part from your URL:

```
#page
```

so that the URL looks like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/mobile-software-
applications/id6018?mt=8&letter=A&page=2");
```

(line break added for readability)

the hash part must never be sent to the server, it is used by the browser to navigate to parts of the page.